# Is there is any work around to get result according to first letter in angucomplete angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using angularjs directive [angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) in which is there is possibility to get results according to text first select. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/s08nypfd/) to clear your view.

```
angular.module('myapp', []).filter('myfilter', function(){
return function(input, text){
    return input.filter(function(item){
        return item.startsWith(text);
    });
};
});

function myctrl($scope){
$scope.filter_text = 'a';
$scope.items = [
    'abc',
    'bca'
 ];
}
```

If a person type 'de' its dropdown suggesting 'Andhra pradesh' instead of 'Delhi' because 'Andhra Pradesh' starts with letter 'A'. As i want it to search according to its first letter.

Thanks